# Can't type an error message using req.flash() method

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

I am trying to give the user the error message when he/she try to sign up for a new account.
I am using nodejs, express, mongodb, passport, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose and flash messages.
The user schema contains only username and password
When I try to console.log the errors they all look like this:
ctor [error-name] : error message

the code I am using is :

```
router.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username});
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            req.flash("error", err);
            return res.render("register");
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
            req.flash("success", "Welcome to YelpCamp " + user.username);
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        });
    });
});
```

so if the user enter a username that is existed before the error look like this :

```
ctor [UserExistsError]: A user with the given username is already registered
```

and if there was no username given the error look like this :

```
ctor [MissingUsernameError]: No username was given
```

and so on
the problem is that i can't extract the error messages from the lines above using this code :

```
req.flash("error", err);
```

How can I print the error message please.

Comment: just `redirect()` to `GET /register` instead of `render()`.

Comment: sorry man bu it didn't work

Comment: this line : req.flash("error", err);
returns [object object] instead of this "A user with the given username is already registered", I want to know if there is a way to extract this message from this line
"ctor [UserExistsError]: A user with the given username is already registered" if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

The way passport-local-mongoose works is that when it found a duplicate user in the database, it will throw an error.

```
//node_modules/passport-local-mongoose/index.js

const promise = Promise.resolve()
            .then(() => {
                if (!user.get(options.usernameField)) {
                    throw new errors.MissingUsernameError(options.errorMessages.MissingUsernameError);
                }
            })
            .then(() => this.findByUsername(user.get(options.usernameField)))
            .then(existingUser => {
                if (existingUser) {
                    throw new errors.UserExistsError(options.errorMessages.UserExistsError);
                }
            })
            .then(() => user.setPassword(password))
            .then(() => user.save());
```

So, the message you see in console.log(err) is actually an error object.

```
//console
ctor [UserExistsError]: A user with the given username is already registered
ctor [MissingUsernameError]: No username was given
```

Typically, when extracting message from an error object, we use `error.message`.

```
req.flash("error", err.message);
```

So, the code should looks like:

```
if(err){
            console.log(err.message);
            req.flash("error", err.message);
            res.redirect('/register');
        }
```

Also, as a side note, `res.render("register")` will not do anything, because you have to let the page refresh to show the flash message.

Check https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_message for more information.